# Linux Websocket protocol version 8 vs 13

Tags: linux, websocket, jetty

I have strange  problem with websocket application in flash and Java server on jetty.
From some moment client have started to open connection with version 8, but server supports only 13 version.

I really does not catch what is the problem and where is the source of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket version 8 is a draft implementation of WebSocket. (in other words, a non-final early experimental version of WebSocket)

WebSocket version 13 is the finalized version of WebSocket Standard ([RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)).

See the IANA registry for WebSocket Versions for more detail:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml#version-number

If you see clients sending WebSocket version 8, then those clients are old and have not yet supported the finalized WebSocket standard (version 13).

The Jetty project participated in the development of the WebSocket standard.  Older versions of Jetty (specifically Jetty 7 and Jetty 8) were used to test out various discussions and experiments in the WebSocket spec, and supports [Hixie-75](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-75) (the proposed WebSocket protocol) all the way up to version 13 (the ietf standardized WebSocket protocol).  As expected, the support for experimental draft versions stayed at the level of "experimental", and are not maintained.  However, you can enable them in Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 with the `minVersion` init-parameter on your servlet.

Starting with Jetty 9, all experimental draft versions of WebSocket were dropped.  Only version 13 is supported.

Note: There is an open bug to remove the experimental drafts from Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=418140

Comment: thank for you comment.
I have found that http://www.websocket.org/echo.html uses v13.
How can be that flash client, which I run in same browser, uses v8 ?

Comment: The flash client implements its own WebSocket protocol, it doesn't use the one provided by the browser.  I suspect you just have to upgrade the flash library you are using for websocket in your flash project.

Comment: I have latest for Linux, 11.2. It worked fine.. before, but something happens now

Comment: No, you misunderstood, not Flash itself, but the library you are using _with_ your flash application that is doing WebSocket for you. Such as [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) or [AS3WebSocket](https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket).  Upgrade that, rebuild your flash application, deploy it, try again.